# Best formula for optimization?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix where each column is a different brand.

Each row is a different category.

I have a separate matrix which is the desired outcome.

I need to mix the first martix to find the most optimal outcome of % to = the second matrix.

```
First matrix: C |  105 130 120
              P |  1   3   5
              F |  2   4    2
```

goal is to design a mix that has these attributes:

```
Optimal:      C |  245
              P |  6
              F |  7
```

What formula is this?

Comment: "its not the code that is stumping me but the math" -- that almost certainly means you have asked this question in the wrong place

Comment: perhaps you could get people interested if you explain in more detail how the optimization needs to be done, and the best site for this question could be https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are actually searching for a solution to a set of linear equations. Assuming you want to "mix" each of the columns of the matrix to get to the final target, you're actually looking for a vector x such that `target = M @ x`. The solution is to multiply by the inverse, `x = inv(M) @ target`. Using numpy, this translates to

```
import numpy

M = numpy.array([[105, 130, 120],
                 [1, 3, 5],
                 [2, 4, 2]])

target = numpy.array([[245], [6], [7]])

x = numpy.linalg.inv(M)@target
```

x is

```
array([[0.11940299],
       [1.57462687],
       [0.23134328]])
```

Comment: I would guess this is intended to be an integer programming problem, not straight linear algebra.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "interact"  - they are separately specified.

Comment: Who said "interact"? I certainly didn't.

Comment: OP deleted their question.